# Is there a way to make text look better in java using the libgdx framework?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using the libgdx framework and java for this android game. I want to draw a text but I hate the way it looks because its too rigid. Is there a way to make it look better?

This is what I have so far:

```
BitmapFont font_for_text = new BitmapFont();
font_for_text.scale((ppuX*0.02f));
font_for_text.draw(spb, "GOALS: ", 15, 15);
```

Let me know if further explanation is required.

Comment: You might be looking for https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts but I found them confusing so I didn't invest time in figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

you need to look into FreeTypeFonts. It will not only allow you to choose your own font but you can define the size of the font before generating it so you dont have to scale anything.

Heres some code from an app where I used it:

```
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator2 = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Font/sans.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter font = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    font.size = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/12;
    sans = generator.generateFont(font);
```

Be careful though, don't regenerate the font instead make it something static or put it in a singleton.